# Scrolling to the bottom of a div with newly inserted content

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is initially empty, but with JavaScript I fill with content. I'd like to scroll to the bottom of the div but nothing is happening. Do I have to wait or do something before scrolling?

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "<p>lots of HTML content</p>";
document.getElementById("div").scrollTop = document.getElementById("div").scrollHeight;
```

Comment: I don't know if there is any other relevant code that we're not seeing here, but this exact pattern seems to work for me at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-boyd-msf6y?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: What device and browser are you using? I’ve just tried the sandbox @Nathan Chappell put up and it scrolls without problems on iPadIOS13.

Comment: Chrome on Windows and ChromeOS. @NathanChappell I just tried your sandbox code and it stayed at the top of the div for me, just showing the numbers from 0 to 13 unless I scrolled down.

Comment: it seems to work if I add `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("div"));` between the two lines of code. Am I using the right tool?

Comment: @GFL okay, I've simplified the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-boyd-msf6y?file=/index.html) and put all the code in one place, and it works just fine for me on windows/chrome.  If it still doesn't work, then maybe you need to reinstall your browser?  Maybe there is some obscure setting or plugin that is interfering?